# Should I upsample both my training as my test set?

Tags: unbalanced-classes

I have a highly unbalanced dataset (1000 vs 60). Where I want to use upsampling. The real life distribution of the problem (predicting no show) is probably also very highly imbalanced. My question is two-fold

1) I know that I should keep the distribution of my training and test set as close to the real life setting so that the distributions are identical, so should I do upsampling?

2) If I should upsample. Should I upsample both my training and test set, or only the training set? Imagine my training set (750 vs 45) and test set (250 vs 15). Should I bring it to (750 vs 750) and (250 vs 250), or to (750 vs 750) and (250 vs 15)?

Any relevant papers concerning this problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer depends on whether you are using a probabilistic classifier or not: ie does the model produce an estimate of probability of being class A, or just a hard decision A or B?

1) If you use a (well calibrated) probabilistic classifier (logistic regression, most neural nets xgboost with logloss) then it probably doesn't matter too much (and you readjust your prediction proportionately). If you don't use a probabilistic classifier then you have to rebalance, and then ...???

2) don't adjust your test set -

I suspect any differences might be random/problem specific - ie suck it and see.